# S5 shows charge icon but is not charging the battery. Tried three different batteries

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-5

In the last couple of days, my S5 stopped charging the battery normally, even though the charge icon is displayed as charging in the top right.

When plugged into a wall outlet with the wider USB 3.0 cable, it usually fully charges in an hour or so.

Now, it's not charging battery even when plugged in overnight.   I've swapped cables, swapped wall adapter, and even tried a brand new spare battery.   Nothing improves this situation.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you charge in safe mode?  Try using [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere) to measure while charging. If no current is being shown, it's almost certain hardware Issue. Likely USB port fault. Some phones display charging icon on being connected to charger and not necessarily charging!

Comment: Can try cleaning the [charging port](http://thedroidguy.com/2016/09/samsung-galaxy-s5-shows-charging-icon-even-not-charging-issue-related-problems-1064854) and other things suggested here